# How many iOS devices should I take into account for window sizes (point values)?

Tags: ios, xcode, window, device, uiscreen

I've been working on setting my app up for all device sizes.  I'm going to hard code all the frames (through my calculations) and use

```
CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

to obtain window size in points.  I've tried Auto layout, constraints, size classes (the whole nine thousand yards) and I find it useful for projects that aren't mine.  I prefer my views, buttons, and labels to not be constrained to any particular x/y coordinate point unless they have to.

So, how many iPhone and iPad screen sizes do I need to account for to get this right and let users with any phone/tablet play my game?

I currently worked out all frames for 2G, 3G, 3GS, 4, 4s (320x480); 5, 5s, 6 (display zoom) (320x568); 6, 6 plus (display zoom) (375x667); 6 plus and 7 (414x736) and the app in those versions looks great so far.

I don't want to forget a device and end up getting denied approval for submission to app store.  I've also looked for a straightforward list online for all devices and found none.

Can anyone help me out?

************ UPDATE ***************

Just wanted to post a follow-up question here.  I was wondering how to keep the aspect ratio at 1:1?  My 105x105 pt. button has a 7:40 and I can't seem to get around it.  I'm using a custom image for the background so that may or may not have something to do with it (?).

Here's a snapshot of the Xib in interface builder.

[UIButton in IB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUTUp.png)

Comment: What you are planning is the worst possible solution. Don't do it.

Comment: and if a new one gets added in the future? this sounds like its going to be a nightmare to maintain

Comment: I figured that, but are there other solutions?  I had written about this problem with the limitations of Auto layout and constraints previously.  When I hard coded all frames for my main screen for a 357x667 device, and previewed the screen, I found that my hard code did exactly what I wanted.  Whereas, no matter what I did, constraint building always threw me by the wayside.

Comment: Imagine a circular button in the center of a 320x568 screen 60 points down from the top.  When you take that button to a 375x667 screen 3 things are going to happen.  The height and width will equally increase, AND the y-position of the button will increase (move down the screen).  With constraint building, this scenario is (for the time being for what I can do) impossible.

Comment: Seeing as this is a terrible way to go about things, what else should I look in to?

Comment: Don't base anything on the screen size, ever. Base things on the view controller view's size. If you want something centered on the view, set it's center to the parent view's center.

Comment: Autolayout isn't as bad as it seems!  You should really try and use it.   iPhone 7+ (414x736), iPhone 7 is 375x667, iPad, iPad Air 768x1024, iPad Pro 1024x1366.  That, with your list is everything for now.

Comment: I get that idea, I've been able to forgo calculations for that aspect.  However, again, getting back to the original problem...there doesn't seem to be a clear cut solution for what I described above with the button (That satisfies those 3 after-effects for increased screen real estate).  I really would prefer not hard coding this portion, but if I have to to make the app look better than I will.

Comment: @CarienvanZyl  Take a look at my comment about the button and how I want it to respond to increased screen real estate.  I have not been able to make Autolayout satisfy my wishes.

Comment: @AnthonyShintoluggenprog Can you explain, exactly what you want to do with the button?  Do you have another question for that, that you can point me to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and did your example to show you essentially how it could work with auto layout.  Of course there are other ways to accomplish the same thing...

> Imagine a circular button in the center of a 320x568 screen 60 points down from the top. When you take that button to a 375x667 screen 3 things are going to happen. The height and width will equally increase, AND the y-position of the button will increase (move down the screen). With constraint building, this scenario is (for the time being for what I can do) impossible.

I used 4 constraints

- Button vertically aligned -114 from center (adjust as necessary)
- Button horizontally aligned to center
- Button aspect ratio 1:1
- Superview width is 3.75 multiple of button (adjust as necessary)
  width

[image]

On iPhone 5

[image]

On iPhone 6s

[image]

There's a bit of an optical illusion created here because of the difference in screen size, but the button is both lowered and bigger on the iPhone 6s compared to the 5.  That's what you were looking for.

Comment: Wow...I stand brilliantly corrected.  I did not know you could do that with the vertical centering constraint at all.  I've been trying for weeks to make that happen with my Play button....Frankie, thank you very much, you're a life-saver!